# How to prevent to change slider's value by clicking on slider in PYQT?

Tags: python, pyqt

In PYQT, how we can change the slider's value just by drag the slider tong?
If you click on the slider, the tong moves and it causes sliderReleased signal is not triggered.

Comment: The `sliderReleased` is an important signal that should only be emitted and received when the slider *handle* is actually released. Are you sure you need to connect to it? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change its pageStep to 0

```
slider = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAbstractSlider()
slider.setPageStep(0)
```

pageStep contains the number of steps that changes value when you press on a slider without touching its tongue.